# Getting an error for user defaults in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, location, nsuserdefaults

I am fairly new to Xcode and I think it is the organization of my code that is developing this error
What I am aiming for is as long as the user is within the radius of x miles they can get 10 points when they click a button and I do want these points to save

what my view controller has is the map that shows the user's current location, a label that says "total points" and a button that when pressed, will check if the user is at the desired location

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController ,CLLocationManagerDelegate

{

    @IBOutlet var pointsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var getPointsOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!


    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    var Points = 0



    override func viewDidLoad()

    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //getting an error for the line below saying "cannot call value of non-funtion type 'UserDefaults' "


        var PointsDefault = UserDefaults.standard

        if (PointsDefault.value(forKey: "Points") != nil)
        {

//got an error here saying " 'Any? is not convertible to 'NSInteger!' "
            Points = PointsDefault.valueForKey("Points") as NSInteger!

//getting an error below saying "cannot assign value of type 'NSString' to type 'String?' "
            pointsLabel.text = NSString(format: "Points : %i", Points)
        }



        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()


    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations     locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D =     CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude,     location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion =     MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.map.showsUserLocation = true



    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    @IBAction func getPoints(_ sender: Any)
    {

        if let userLocation = manager.location
        {

            let desiredLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 50.000000, longitude: -80.000000)
            let radius: Double = 0.25 // miles
            let distance = desiredLocation.distance(from: userLocation)
            if distance < radius
            {
                Points += 10
//getting an error below saying "cannot assign value of type 'NSString' to type 'String?' "
                pointsLabel.text = NSString(format: "Points : %i", Points)

            }

        //getting an error for the line below saying to delete the () but when i do i get plenty more errors

            var PointsDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            PointsDefault.setValue(Points, forKey: "Points")
            PointsDefault.synchronize()

        }


    }


    }
```

[image]

UPDATE: all the errors in my code have been fixed, but when I run it I get these errors

Comment: Please include the error message you're getting.

Comment: okay i provided the message in my new edit^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` has been changed from a method to a property and is now called `UserDefaults.standard` in Swift 3.

*(edited)*

Regarding the label, you can try casting to `String`:

```
pointsLabel.text = NSString(format: "Points : %i", Points) as? String
```

or just using string interpolation:

```
pointsLabel.text = "Points: \(Points)"
```

You can get integer values from `UserDefaults` like this:

```
Points = PointsDefault.integer(forKey: "Points")
```

Also, for easier reading of your code, you should use lowercase initials for your variables (`var`) and constants (`let`), and uppercase initials for type names (classes, structs, ...).

Comment: I just uploaded an image in my question above of what errors I get when I run the app, your help would be very appreciated

Comment: At first glance, those issues do not appear to be directly related to the code you posted. You may have issues in some other parts of your app, that can not be diagnosed just by looking at those messages. You should use the Xcode debugger and/or Instruments to understand what is causing those issues. In particular, make sure there are no errors in your storyboard or nibs, since some of those leaks mention UINib.